# TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, customvalidator, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting an error everytime I submit my post without an image, submission of the image is optional because I run an `if` condition before appending the imagePath. working on a MEAN stack up to which I am new in.

**mime-type-validator**

```
    import { AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable, Observer, of } from "rxjs";

export const mimeType = (
  control: AbstractControl
): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> => {
  if (typeof(control.value) === 'string') {
    return of(null);
  }
  const file = control.value as File;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const frObs = Observable.create(
    (observer: Observer<{ [key: string]: any }>) => {
      fileReader.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
        const arr = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer).subarray(0, 4);
        let header = "";
        let isValid = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          header += arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        switch (header) {
          case "89504e47":
            isValid = true;
            break;
          case "ffd8ffe0":
          case "ffd8ffe1":
          case "ffd8ffe2":
          case "ffd8ffe3":
          case "ffd8ffe8":
            isValid = true;
            break;
          default:
            isValid = false; // Or you can use the blob.type as fallback
            break;
        }
        if (isValid) {
          observer.next(null);
        } else {
          observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
        }
        observer.complete();
      });
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
  );
  return frObs;
};
```

**create-post-component**

```
  import { Component, Inject, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'
import { PostModel } from 'src/app/Models/post.model';
import { PostsService } from 'src/app/Services/posts.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router' 
import { mimeType } from 'src/app/auth/Validators/mime-type.validator'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-post',
  templateUrl: './create-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-post.component.css']
})
export class CreatePostComponent {

  public mode = 'user';
  private postId : string;
  public post: PostModel;
  isLoading : boolean = false;
  imagePreview: string;
  

  PostForm = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
    content: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
    image: new FormControl(null,  {validators:[], asyncValidators: [mimeType] })
  })
 
  constructor(public postsService: PostsService, public route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){
    
  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap)=>{
      if(paramMap.has('postId')){
        this.mode = 'edit';
        this.postId = paramMap.get('postId');
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.postsService.getPost(this.postId).subscribe(postdata =>{
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.post = {id: postdata._id, title: postdata.title, content: postdata.content , imagePath: postdata.imagePath};
          this.PostForm.setValue({ title: this.post.title, content: this.post.content, image: this.post.imagePath });
        });
      }
      else{
        this.mode = 'user';
        this.postId = null;
      }
    })
  }

  
  onAddPost()
  
  {
    if(this.PostForm.invalid){
      return;
    }
    this.isLoading = true;
    if (this.mode === 'user'){
      this.postsService.addPosts(this.PostForm.value.title, this.PostForm.value.content, this.PostForm.value.image)
      this.isLoading = false;
      Swal.fire({
        position: 'center',
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Post added!',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000
      })
    }
    
    else{
      this.postsService.updatePosts(
        this.postId,
        this.PostForm.value.title,
        this.PostForm.value.content,
        this.PostForm.value.image
      );
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');
    }
    this.PostForm.reset();
  }
  

  onImagePicked(event: Event){
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.PostForm.patchValue({image: file});
    this.PostForm.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imagePreview = reader.result as string;
    };
    
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
    
  }
}
```

**posts-service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PostModel } from '../Models/post.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable(
  { providedIn: 'root' }
)

export class PostsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private posts: PostModel[] = [];
  private postsUpdated = new Subject<PostModel[]>()

  getPosts() {
    this.http.get<{ message: string, posts: any }>('http://localhost:3300/api/posts')
      .pipe(
        map((postData) => {
          return postData.posts.map(post => {
            return {
              title: post.title,
              content: post.content,
              id: post._id,
              imagePath: post.imagePath
            }
          })
        }))
      .subscribe(transformedPosts => {
        this.posts = transformedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts])  //updating the posts so that it is available to the rest of the app
      })
  }
  getUpdatedPostsListener() {
    return this.postsUpdated.asObservable()
  }

  getPost(id: string) {
    // return {...this.posts.find( p => p.id === id)} //p implies each post, and p.id implies that post's id

    return this.http.get<{ _id: string; title: string; content: string, imagePath: string }>("http://localhost:3300/api/posts/" + id);
  }

  addPosts(title: string, content: string, image: File) {
    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('title', title);
    postData.append('content', content);
    if(image != undefined){
      postData.append('image', image, title);
    }
    this.http.post<{ message: string, post: PostModel }>('http://localhost:3300/api/posts', postData).subscribe((responseData) => {
      const post: PostModel = { id: responseData.post.id, title: title, content: content, imagePath: responseData.post.imagePath }
      this.posts.push(post);
      this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
    })


  }

  updatePosts(id: string, title: string, content: string, image: File | string) {
    let postData: PostModel | FormData;
    if (typeof image === "object") {
      postData = new FormData();
      postData.append("id", id);
      postData.append("title", title);
      postData.append("content", content);
      if(image != undefined){
        postData.append("image", image, title);
      }
      
    } else {
      postData = {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        content: content,
        imagePath: image
      };
    }
    this.http
      .put("http://localhost:3300/api/posts/" + id, postData)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const updatedPosts = [...this.posts];
        const oldPostIndex = updatedPosts.findIndex(p => p.id === id);
        const post: PostModel = {
          id: id,
          title: title,
          content: content,
          imagePath: ""
        };
        updatedPosts[oldPostIndex] = post;
        this.posts = updatedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
        // this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }

  deletePosts(postId: string) {
    this.http.delete('http://localhost:3300/api/posts/' + postId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        const updatedPosts = this.posts.filter(post => post.id !== postId);
        this.posts = updatedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);

      })
  }
}
```